# pisa не отображает utf-8

Tags: python, django

при рендере pdf файла, появляются черные квадраты. и выдаёт следующею ошибку

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 11: invalid start
>   byte

css и шрифт ttf подгружает. Однако не отображает корректно кирилицу. что делать  ?

моя views.py на создание pdf.

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        import sys
        import locale
        print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
        print(locale.getpreferredencoding()) # win32/rus
        print(sys.stdout.encoding) # win32
        patht = './templates/pdf_gen.html'
        template = get_template('pdf_gen.html')
        print(patht)
        with codecs.open(patht, encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            html = f.read() 
        context = {
            "contract_number": contract_number,
            # "len_speca":len_speca,
            # "speca": speca,
            # "spect": spect,
        }
        # html = template.render(context)
        # return    HttpResponse(html)

        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_gen.html' , context)

        if html:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/pdf')
            # response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/force-download')
            filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("213231231")
            content = "inline; filename = %s" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return  HttpResponse("Not found")
```

мой файл utils.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.conf import settings
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import os

def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
    if uri.find(settings.MEDIA_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ''))
    elif uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ''))
    else:
        path = None
    print('___________________________________',path)
    return path


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    # pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    # pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding="utf-8", link_callback=fetch_pdf_resources)
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding="UTF-8", link_callback=fetch_pdf_resources)

    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

мой template.html

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css_styles/pdf_css.css' %}" />
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css_styles/times-new-roman.ttf' %}" />
        <!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>


    </head>
    <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как и пред. раз решением задачи указывать прямой путь к ттф файлу в link_callback. при условии что в hmtl and css подтягивается шрифт и указант font-face font-family

```
def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
    if uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != 0:
        path = < FULL PATH TO TTF FILE>
    elif uri.find(settings.MEDIA_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ''))
    elif uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ''))
    else:
        path = None
    print(path)
    return path
```